# Pytest does not detect correctly a datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pytest

I have an issue on pytest. I want to make a UNIT TEST on a function returning a datetime.
The basic check will be to check the return is well a datetime.
I will use the assert method

```
assert (isinstance(dte_Date, datetime.datetime))
```

When I test the code normally, I get the following results which are correct:

```
dte_modif = os.path.getmtime(str_pathFile)
dte_Date =  dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(dte_modif)
print(dte_Date)
print(type(dte_Date))
print(isinstance(dte_Date, datetime.datetime))
assert (isinstance(dte_Date, datetime.datetime))
```

Result:

```
2022-04-14 15:24:17.809005
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
True
```

When I launch Pytest I get:

```
<built-in method fromtimestamp of type object at 0x00007FFC0D95C650>
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
False
```

and :

```
>      assert (isinstance(dte_modif, datetime.datetime))
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = isinstance(<built-in method fromtimestamp of type object at 0x00007FFC0D95C650>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>)
E        +    where <class 'datetime.datetime'> = datetime.datetime

FAILED ... - AssertionError: assert False
```

Comment: ```os.path.getmtime()``` doesn't return a datetime.datetime object.  It returns a floating point value.   as in : https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime

Comment: if you `import datetime as dt` in your unittest script, you'll need to assert `isinstance(dte_Date, dt.datetime)`, not datetime.datetime